# how to set min and max for an attribute in Julia?

Tags: struct, attributes, julia

I have this struct and I need to set a min/max Value for it

```
struct Field <:AbstractModel
 type::Type
 default::String
 description::String
 min::Int
 max::Int
end
```

for example min should not be lower then 0 and the max is 10

Comment: Is this a min/max for each instance, or for the struct in general? You can use an inner constructor (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/), together with the ArgCheck package, depending on what you want.

Comment: thank you I did not know about the ArgCheck package

Comment: The `type::Type` signature is a bit unusual. Normally, I would use `type::DataType` or `type::Type{T}`. What is its purpose here?